# Libgdx actions to image is applied to whole actors

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to make the Image fade out then fade in and this is working but the background image is also fade out then fade in 
Also when I apply the rotation Action (which is commented) it rotates the image only one time although I put it on the event Touchup, while the fading in and out is applied on each touch but fading applied on image and background
: here where I apply the action in this class:

```
   public class MainButtons {
    public Viewport viewport;
    public Stage stage;
    public boolean centerPressed;

    public Image fire;
    public Image center;
    public Sound flap;

    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public static Table table;


    //Constructor.
    public MainButtons(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new StretchViewport(KidTele.V_WIDTH,KidTele.V_HIEGH,camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport, spriteBatch);
        //InputMultiplexer this is why only input handling  from controller
        flap= Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("one.mp3"));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        fire= new Image(new Texture("cars/fire.png"));

        //buttonone.setSize(10, 5);


        menuTable();
        defineCenter();

    }
    public void defineCenter()
    {
        center=new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("0.png")));

        center.setBounds(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 5f, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 3f, viewport.getWorldWidth() / 1.5f, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 3f);
        center.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                centerPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                //center.setOrigin(center.getWidth()/2,center.getHeight()/2);
                //center.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.rotateTo(360, 2), Actions.fadeIn(1)));
                center.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(1), Actions.fadeIn(1)));
                centerPressed = false;
            }
        });
        //center.setVisible(false);
        stage.addActor(center);
    }
    public void draw() {
        stage.draw();
    }
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
}
```

and this is the code of the screen:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private KidTele game;
    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gameport;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    private MainButtons mainButtons;
    private Texture background;
    private Sound flap;
    public PlayScreen(KidTele game)
    {
        this.game=game;
        gamecam=new OrthographicCamera();
        gameport=new StretchViewport(KidTele.V_WIDTH,KidTele.V_HIEGH,gamecam);
        //stage=new Stage(gameport,((KidTele) game).batch);
        background=new Texture("background2.png");
        gamecam.position.set(gameport.getWorldWidth()/2f,gameport.getWorldHeight()/2f,0);
        b2dr=new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        world=new World(new Vector2(0,0.8f),true);
        flap= Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("one.mp3"));
        mainButtons=new MainButtons(game.batch);
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
    public void handleinput(float dt)
    {

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)) {
            mainButtons.stopMusic();
            game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
        }

    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {
        handleinput(dt);
        world.step(1 /60f, 6, 2);
        //player.update(dt);

        gamecam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

         b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();

        game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0, gameport.getWorldWidth(), gameport.getWorldHeight());
        game.batch.end();
        mainButtons.stage.act();
        mainButtons.stage.draw();
        mainButtons.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gameport.update(width, height);
        mainButtons.resize(width, height);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you call `stage.draw()`, the SpriteBatch may be set to some arbitrary color. In your case, it is set with some partial alpha from fading one of the actors. To fix this, make sure you call `batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)` right before drawing the background, so you can guarantee what color it will be drawn with.

The image is only rotating one time because you are using `rotateTo` and giving it the same value every time. Once it rotates to 360 degrees, each time you call `rotateTo` again, it will already be at 360 degrees, so nothing happens. In your case you should use `rotateBy` instead.

By the way, you are drawing your stage twice when you do this:

```
    mainButtons.stage.draw();
    mainButtons.draw();
```